# aggregation (count, sum) and grouping in Spring Data Jpa Specification

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, specifications, criteria-api

He guys, I'm new one in Java, and i little bit stuck. If it possible to get person like map<Status, Integer> using Specification? I have classes Person and Status, and my business to make endpoint that return those map by filters (sex, age) how works filters i've already understood, but how not using @Query to get map - not. Below my classes:

```
@Entity(name = "persons")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String sex;
    private Status status;
}

@Getter
public enum Status {
    ONLINE,
    OFFLINE,
    BANNED,
    DELETED;
}
```

my endpoint must return
{
ONLINE: 5,
OFFLINE: 17,
BANNED: 2,
DELETED: 4
}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for Projections: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Spring data allows you to do what you ask for using an interface without providing an implementation which is very convenient!

Suppose you have an entity car:

```
@Entity
public class Car {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    private String model;
 
    private String color;
 
    private int year

    // getters and setters
}
```

And you want to retrieve the color and year. You can do so with an interface:

```
public interface ICarProjection {
    String getColor();
    int getYear();
}
```

Make sure the naming of your methods in the interface are identical to that of your entity, this is important.

In your repository you can now use the interface in place of the full entity:

```
public interface CarRepository extends Repository<Car, Long> {
    @Query('xxx')
    List<ICarProjection> getColorAndYear();
}
```

Comment: Re-reading your question I am unsure if you are actually looking for how to perform joins and return multiple table data back. If that is the case, reply back/check this article

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-joining-tables

Note you may need to combine that article with using join fetch in your query if you want the entity to be accessible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to return in my endpoint map where first paramether will be Status and second count how many persons reate this status, answer must be { ONLINE : 5, OFFLINE : 18, BANNED : 2, DELETED: 4}, how to do it using Query i have an idea, but how to do it with grouping and filters in specification i have no idea)) my english very poor, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get map collection on entity but only when you join two tablet using `@ElementCollection` for example.

```
@Entity
public class Store {
  @Id
  protected long id;
 
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "item_quantity",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "store_id") })
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "item")
  @Column(name = "quantity")
  protected Map<String, Integer> itemQuantityMap = new HashMap<>();
```

In your case better way is mapping result lists by stream.

```
List<Person> result = repository.findAll();
var map = result.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getStatus, Person ::getSex))
```

Comment: thank you, but second way very obvious) i wanted to not get all data from db, but even now can't find the answer how to get data use just one query but not with @Query annotation, something like specification or criteria, or its impossible?)

Comment: Yes using projections and result transformation - @TedEllis wrote about that. Anyway remember  that - every dbms  gives you result list first a then can be transformed in memory for several options.